# Apple Mac OS X 10.9.1 Thread 0 crash

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, crash-reports

I keep getting the following crash report when HTTP operations are made from applications, I have Clean my Mac and Avast Anti-virus software installed. Has anybody come across something similar?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libc++abi.dylib                 0x99473571 __dynamic_cast + 18
1   com.apple.security              0x91231365 Security::CssmClient::DbImpl& Security::CssmClient::Object::impl<Security::CssmClient::DbImpl>() const + 53
2   com.apple.security              0x91249cca Security::KeychainCore::Trust::evaluate(bool) + 1886
3   com.apple.security              0x912493cc SecTrustEvaluate + 54
4   com.adobe.AIR                   0x02386d16 0x2000000 + 3697942
5   com.adobe.AIR                   0x02386c40 0x2000000 + 3697728
6   com.adobe.AIR                   0x02386eba 0x2000000 + 3698362
7   com.adobe.AIR                   0x023877d7 0x2000000 + 3700695
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x97887680 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 878
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x978fe3b2 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 91
10  com.adobe.AIR                   0x02386857 0x2000000 + 3696727
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x93c4e304 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x979eb400 __74-[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection(Internal) sendCFChallenge:toSelector:]_block_invoke + 187
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x979194a3 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 56
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x9791945b -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 108
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x979193ce -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 248
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x979192b8 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 76
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x979eb33e -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection(Internal) sendCFChallenge:toSelector:] + 110
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x979eba5a _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge + 50
19  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x905b1c95 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic51_delegate_willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeEP19_CFURLAuthChallenge_block_invoke + 737
20  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x9065a916 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 104
21  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x9058952a ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 25
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x960820e9 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
23  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x90589423 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 135
24  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x906a3156 non-virtual thunk to RunloopBlockContext::multiplexerClientPerform() + 20
25  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x905892dd MultiplexerSource::perform() + 317
26  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x905890fe MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 76
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x960b9e3f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x960aaccb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x960aa3ce __CFRunLoopRun + 1022
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x960a9d5a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x960a9bbb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
32  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x964d3e2d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 259
33  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x964d3bb2 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 526
34  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x964d398d _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 92
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x918895a9 _DPSNextEvent + 1602
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x91888ad0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x9187b35c -[NSApplication run] + 727
38  com.adobe.AIR                   0x02009f72 0x2000000 + 40818
39  com.adobe.AIR                   0x0200a2b8 0x2000000 + 41656
40  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x93c4e2af -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
41  com.1minus1.socialsafe.D675411CF670AA3EFAC13BDD847989BEDE2115E2.1   0x00002f93 RuntimeAppMain(char const*, int) + 371
42  com.1minus1.socialsafe.D675411CF670AA3EFAC13BDD847989BEDE2115E2.1   0x000025c1 start + 53
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the end of your log:

```
41  com.1minus1.socialsafe.D675411CF670AA3EFAC13BDD847989BEDE2115E2.1   0x00002f93 RuntimeAppMain(char const*, int) + 371
42  com.1minus1.socialsafe.D675411CF670AA3EFAC13BDD847989BEDE2115E2.1   0x000025c1 start + 53
```

I'm willing to bet this "socialsafe" program is causing the issue.  Can you disable or uninstall it?